# Being a Base is a Topological Invariant?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I can't find a proof for this. My own attempt follows and **I would value feedback on its validity**.

Let $f: (W, \mathscr S) \to (X, \mathscr T)$ be a homeomorphism, $\mathscr B \subset \mathscr S$ be a base for $ \mathscr S$, and $O$ be any open set in $\mathscr T$.

Then $f^{-1}(O) \in \mathscr S $ and there is some subset $ \mathscr B_1 \subset \mathscr B \subset \mathscr S$ with $\cup \mathscr B_1 = f^{-1}(O)$.

But as $f$ is a bijection, $f( f^{-1}(O)) = O = f(\cup \mathscr B_1) = \cup _{B \in \mathscr B_1} f(B)$.

So, $f(\mathscr B)$ is a base for $\mathscr T$.

(and $f^{-1}:(W, \mathscr S) \to (X, \mathscr T) $  is a homeomorphism too, so the converse follows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof seems correct. For the concluding remark, it might be convenient to state explicitly that you are using that $f$ is open (otherwise you are only proving that every open set is a union of sets in $f(\mathscr{B})$, and you need these to be open).

In general, since bijections preserve all the set-theoretic operations (arbitrary unions & intersections, complements, powersets, and therefor the inclusion relations), and homeos preserve the topology, everything you can express using these will be a topological invariant.